# Remove all non-numeric characters from a string; [^0-9] doesn't match as expected

Tags: php, regex, string, phone-number, sanitization

I'm trying to remove everything from a string but just numbers (0-9).

I thought this would work..

```
echo preg_replace("[^0-9]","",'604-619-5135');
```

But it echos "604-619-5135". What am I missing???

Comment: [Why do the PHP preg_* functions require regexp delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9550899/2943403)

Comment: Your pattern works perfectly when the input string is changed to accommodate it.  [`echo preg_replace("[^0-9]", "this", '0-9 is replaced');`](https://3v4l.org/WX7pO) outputs: `this is replaced`

Answer (score 333, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', '604-619-5135');
```

preg_replace uses PCREs which generally start and end with a `/`.

Comment: The inner/double quoting doesn't have anything to do with PCRE tho. Apparently (in the days before `(?flags)`) the people who designed/wrote the function/API thought it was a good idea to pass the regex flags with the double quoted `/flags` form instead of using an extra function parameter.

Comment: @Qtax: good point, yeah I know that's where we get the word "grep" from ("g/re/p")

Comment: adding character at the las part seems doesnt remove the part

Comment: Or just do it simple and use `/\D/` to get the number or `/\d/` to get the string.

Answer (score 144):

**This is for future developers, you can also try this. Simple too**

```
echo preg_replace('/\D/', '', '604-619-5135');
```

Comment: I have come back 2 the future and I can confirm they have still not found a better way.

Comment: @Eoin to make this pattern "better" add a one-or-more quantifier (`+`) after the `D`.  This allows the regex engine to make longer and therefore fewer replacements.  Imagine standing in front of a carton of eggs.  If I asked you to pick up the dozen eggs, would you do 12 squats or just 1?  Though I like to work out, I'd squat once and pick up all of the eggs as a matter of directness.

Answer (score 15):

You would need to enclose the pattern in a delimiter - typically a slash (/) is used. Try this:

```
echo preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",'604-619-5135');
```

Comment: [A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Answer (score 7):

NOTE: if you are filtering strings containing - sign is not applicable to this answer because - stands for minus sign and is NOT filtered and removed. (like -2, -4 etc). If you still want to use it please remove - characters and then try.

(- + . e) characters are not stripped with this function

a much more practical way for those who do not want to use regex:

```
$data = filter_var($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

note: it works with phone numbers too.

Comment: `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` leaves plus `+` and minus `-` signs, not only digits.

Comment: yes I said it works with phone numbers like +905360000000 leaves out all other characters

Comment: This is e.g. a problem if you try to use it with Whatsapp as WA DOES NOT allow + signs!

Comment: This answer is completely ineffective for the question asked.  Proof: https://3v4l.org/IMQeJ

Comment: if you read manual page for this you can see that your proof contains - character which is allowed for int if you use -2 for example. so you cannot apply this. you can use $str = str_replace("-", "", $str); and apply this filter_var.