# how to exclude everything but numbers in php?

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP code to remove everything but numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604455/php-code-to-remove-everything-but-numbers)

i have a loop that returns some content and i want to filter so that i get back only numbers:

```
foreach ($number as $k => $content) {
    echo "<td>" . $content . "</td>";
}
```

this will return:

```
Sender Number,,
1818233483,, - aaa
1562595441,, - aaa
1870750493,, - aaa
1832677004,, - aaa
1832466803,, - aaa
```

and i want to do some king of regexp or something so i will filter only the numbers:

```
1818233483
1562595441
1870750493
1832677004
1832466803
```

also i'm not sure what characters might be there so i need to check for everything but numbers.

any ideas?
thanks

edit:
i did this:
    $test = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $content);

but i get:

```
Sender Number,,
1818233483
1562595441
1870750493
..
```

Comment: explode on the comma, or if the length is fixed substr(), regex would be over kill

Comment: Does this answer your question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604455/php-code-to-remove-everything-but-numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
foreach ($number as $k => $content) {
    echo "<td>" . preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $content) . "</td>";
}
```

Edit: try this to remove the Sender Number,,

```
foreach($number as $k => $content) {
    if(is_numeric(substr($content, 0, 4)) {
        echo "<td>" . preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $content) . "</td>";
    }
}
```

Comment: i still get the first line `Sender Number,,`. I need to remove all strings from the result

Comment: Are you sure the Sender Number,, is the first element in $number and not hard coded?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing every character that's not a digit with nothing, using preg_replace

```
foreach ($number as $k => $content) {
    echo "<td>" . preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $content) . "</td>";
}
```

A more efficient approach might be to do string processing on the comma, like so:

```
foreach ($number as $k => $content) {
    echo "<td>" . substr($content, 0, strpos( $content, ',')) . "</td>";
}
```