# Why do the PHP preg_* functions require regexp delimiters?

Tags: php, regex

This is bugging me:

Why `preg_match('/pattern/', $haystack)` instead of `preg_match('pattern', $haystack)`? Everything I've seen just states as a fact that they're necessary, and mentions that you can use alternate delimiters.

But, it's a *function* that defines its own interface outside of the string. *It has a flags argument*. Adding intra-string syntax seems capricious.

Is it something inherited from pcre that the authors were just not interested in working around? Yet another perverse fact of PHP? Or is there a justification?

Comment: Why should they make delimiters optional? They are **Perl-compatible regular expressions** after all. Also, the `$flags` argument in PHP's PCRE functions is not where you put modifiers, unlike the `flags` argument in JavaScript's `RegExp()` constructor.

Comment: Lost in the history of PHP development.  Maybe the Chinese philosopher, F\*\*k, knows.  Maybe its because the authors didn't want you to use a separate arg for the flag modifiers.

Comment: @BoltClock: My question is *why do they exist at all?* The delimiters are part of Perl's syntax, they delimit the regex literal. The PHP regex functions take a string, which already has a perfectly good delimiter in the `'`s that appear at the beginning and end of the string. And I know that the `$flags` isn't used for flags. That's just dumb.

Comment: If you really must know *why*, please ask the original author, not SO. It doesn't sound like you'd be satisfied with anyone else's response (and likely not even theirs).

Comment: @quodlibetor If you are really bothered by the delimiters and the implementation, you can implement your own `my_preg_match()` which accepts a regex without delimiters and adds them, wrapping `preg_match()` internally.

Comment: @salathe: I am curious, and would accept any reasonably correct answer. But if the correct answer is "For compatibility" I would like a link to someone explicitly saying that they're doing it for compatibility, or something. I asked the question hoping that there is a cool or interesting reason for the PHP syntax, because as it stands I think it was a bad decision on the author's part. But I'm not asking anyone to justify it, I'm just asking if there is something more than I learned from reading the docs.

Comment: If you're asking why the delimiters are there in PCRE, then this has literally nothing to do with PHP. PCRE is not a PHP project.

Comment: It is not for compatibility in the sense of the underlying library *requiring* it. Internally, the string is parsed to separate out the delimiters, pattern and pattern modifiers before calling the pcre library.  A *hint* at a possible reason for including the delimiters and modifiers within the "regex" string is that what is now `preg_match` was once called `perl_match` (though not in the PHP source, which had `pcre_match`): the hint being that one would copy and paste the match regex from a Perl script and have it work.

Comment: (continued) I'll repeat, there is no *technical* reason why the regex parameter *requires* delimiters (since the modifiers could easily be another parameter entirely). As an aside, if the pattern modifiers ("flags") were to be separated from the pattern then the `RegexIterator` would have *three* separate "flags" arguments!

Comment: @BoltClock: Part of my question is whether this was inherited from PCRE: I don't know where this comes from, even though I think it's *not* a PCRE thing. I *think* PHP has to parse the string and eliminate all the quoted delimiters, parse the flags at the end and turn those into flags passed into PCRE functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The delimiters are for compatibility with Perl.  Perl regular expressions use the delimiters, and rely on the end delimiter to signify the start [of modifier flags](http://php.net/manual/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), like `i` for case insensitivity, for example.

```
// Match alpha-numeric, case insensitive, multiline
preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+$/im', $input);
```

The optional flags argument to `preg_match()` does not implement the regular expression flags like `i` that follow the second delimiter.  They serve a different function, and indeed `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` is the only flag available there.  This is not to say the regex flags could not have been implemented as another function parameter.  They certainly could have, but Perl-compatibility is the goal here.

PHP is not the only language that borrows directly from Perl to implement regular expressions.  JavaScript does to some degree, and Ruby even implements Perl's `=~` operator for regular expression matches.

Comment: This might be true, but "For compatibility with Perl" doesn't really make sense: the delimiters are a syntactic feature of Perl, not PHP. Flags could very easily have been put into the already existing `flags` argument of the preg_* functions. The shallow effects of delimiters on the syntax don't affect compatibility on anything like a deep level.

Comment: @quodlibetor PHP is not the only language that implements PCRE with delimiters. Ruby does too, and JavaScript to some degree as well. Could they be implemented differently? Sure could. Does it make sense to implement them differently? Not sure about that...

Comment: PHP is the only language that puts the delimiters *inside of strings*. Which use `'` or `"`" as their delimiters. Ruby and JS both took Perl's syntax for regular expressions: You don't write `'/pattern/'` in them, you write `/pattern/`. It's a language feature, not a function, in other languages.

Comment: @quodlibetor That is true. PHP is in general, a language awash in inconsistencies legacy architectural oddities.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was done for interoperability, so you can copy&paste pattern from/to another language and not having to convert pattern options to/from PHP flags.

Answer (score 0):

The delimiter is for Perl compatibility (thus, Perl Compatible Regular Expressions, or PCRE). The pattern also includes any modifiers you choose to use, and they must be placed *after* the closing delimiter.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it something inherited?

The truth is every programming language needs a standard so PCRE is a better standard. [click](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Perl-derived_regular_expressions)