# PHP: Why is the pattern string in preg_match() enclosed in slashes?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Why is the pattern string enclosed in forward slashes in php preg_match() function? Is it just a convention due to some historical reasons or part of the php syntax?

Comment: *string enclosed in forward slashes* it is your / his style can be anything but the character should not take place in regex, if so, this char must be escaped .. for my part, i use @ or pipe |

Comment: It's part of the regex syntax, not PHP - it's the same in Perl, and many other languages. Utilities such as [sed use it too](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/unix-sed-tutorial-replace-text-inside-a-file-using-substitute-command/).

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [Why do the PHP preg_* functions require regexp delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550899/why-do-the-php-preg-functions-require-regexp-delimiters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is convention. In many languages (Javascript, Perl, ...) the slashes are a language construct to define a Regular Expression.

In PHP the pattern is always a string but it contains two parts. The expression itself and modifiers. The slashes enclose the expression to separate them from the modifiers. Any non-alphanumeric character is allowed for to be used as delimiter for the expression. You might see `^`, `~`, `#`, `@` or others.

```
DELIMITER EXPRESSION DELIMITER MODIFIERS
    /         .*         /         x
```

It is possible to use the brackets, too. Unlike other characters they can still be used in the expression the same way.

```
DELIMITER EXPRESSION DELIMITER MODIFIERS
    (         .*         )         x
```

I suggest using `()` as delimiters because it reflects the match array.

```
preg_match('(.(.*))', 'FOO', $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "FOO"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "OO"
}
```