# how to get the string between two character in this case?

Tags: php

I want to get the string between "yes""yes"

eg.

```
yes1231yesyes4567yes
```

output:

```
1231,4567
```

How to do it in php?
may be there are 1 more output '' between yesyes right?

Comment: Will it always be digits between the strings?

Comment: may be 9yes123yes12 and want i need is only between yes

Answer (score 4):

In this *particular* example, you could use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) with a regex to capture digits between "yes" and "yes":

```
preg_match_all("/yes(\d+)yes/", $your_string, $output_array);

print_r($output_array[1]);

// Array
// (
//     [0] => 1231
//     [1] => 4567
// )
```

And to achieve your desired output:

```
echo implode(',', $output_array[1]); // 1231,4567
```

**Edit:** side reference, if you need a looser match that will simply match all sets of numbers in a string e.g. in your comment `9yes123yes12`, use the regex: `(\d+)` and it will match `9`, `123` and `12`.

Comment: `\d+` means "match any number (digit) that occurs at least once". *edit* it's the same as `[0-9]+`

Comment: thank , how about if i want to get the number of the string "we123a"
is it preg_match_all("/we(\d+)a/", $your_string, $output_array);

Comment: Yes. This all totally depends on your application though, there is likely to be a better solution. If all you want is the numbers, just use `/(\d+)/` as the regex assuming they have anything other than numbers on either side of them (or the start or end of the string).

Comment: `preg_match_all()`* - you must be doing something else incorrectly: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/61P

Comment: oh yes~ i put "/a" instead of "a/"......sorry that i wasted your time.
1 more thing i want to know why the array[0] is we123a , but not 123

Comment: @SuenFalendo no worries. [Have a read through the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) - it's your best friend. The default "flags" setting for `preg_match_all()` is `$matches[0] is an array of full pattern matches, $matches[1] is an array of strings matched by the first parenthesized subpattern`

Answer (score 0):

Good Evening,

If you are referring to extracting the digits (as shown in your example) then you can achieve this by referencing the response of Christopher who answered a very similar question on this topic:

[PHP code to remove everything but numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604455/php-code-to-remove-everything-but-numbers)

However, on the other hand, if you are looking to extract all instances of the word "yes" from the string, I would recommend using the [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) method supplied by PHP.

Here is an example that would get you started;

```
str_replace("yes", "", "yes I do like cream on my eggs");
```

I trust that this information is of use.